# Java encryption equals not working

Tags: java, hash

Okay so I have this hash method:

```
public static String getEncodedHash(String password, String salt) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    // Returns only the last part of whole encoded password
    PKCS5S2ParametersGenerator gen = new PKCS5S2ParametersGenerator(new SHA256Digest());

    gen.init(password.getBytes(), salt.getBytes(), DEFAULT_ITERATIONS);
    byte[] dk = ((KeyParameter) gen.generateDerivedParameters(256)).getKey();

    return Base64.toBase64String(dk);
}
```

It hashes fine as far as I can tell, and when it returns a string I compare it to the string I have and they look identical, but the `.equals` method says there not. Anybody got any ideas cause am literally all out

This is the entire `LoginHelper` class:

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import org.spongycastle.crypto.digests.SHA256Digest;
import org.spongycastle.crypto.generators.PKCS5S2ParametersGenerator;
import org.spongycastle.crypto.params.KeyParameter;
import org.spongycastle.util.encoders.Base64;

public class LoginHelper {
    public static final Integer DEFAULT_ITERATIONS = 20000;

    public static boolean passwordCorrect(String enteredPassword, String storedPassword) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        String[] parts = storedPassword.split("\\$");
        String salt = parts[2];
        String storedHash = parts[3];
        String calculatedHash = getEncodedHash(enteredPassword, salt);

        System.out.println(storedHash);
        System.out.println(calculatedHash);

        System.out.println(storedHash.length());
        System.out.println(calculatedHash.length());

        return storedPassword.equals(calculatedHash);
    }

    public static String getEncodedHash(String password, String salt) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        // Returns only the last part of whole encoded password
        PKCS5S2ParametersGenerator gen = new PKCS5S2ParametersGenerator(new SHA256Digest());

        gen.init(password.getBytes(), salt.getBytes(), DEFAULT_ITERATIONS);
        byte[] dk = ((KeyParameter) gen.generateDerivedParameters(256)).getKey();

        return Base64.toBase64String(dk);
    }
}
```

I call with:

```
System.out.println(LoginHelper.passwordCorrect("password","pbkdf2_sha256$20000$wlW7Po1nm1DW$nt9LYWbxwvHIXmyBGUQG7NyPDkrt/2fivN3ws//HzLnks="));
```

Comment: They LOOK identical and they ARE identical, are two different things.
try using WINMerge to compare the Strings.

Comment: can you post the comparison part as well as some input you have tried?

Comment: Write out the length of the string and the numerical value of each character. There may be a space or similar on one of them.

Comment: were can I post entire class?

Comment: also ive trimmed white spaces

Comment: dont need to be there

Comment: Sorry, I meant http://pastebin.com/ for pasting large snippets

Comment: Well I've added pastebin class and how I call it.

Comment: Can you please check that you really call your method with that hash `pbkdf2_sha256$20000$wlW7Po1nm1DW$nt9LYWbxwvHIXmyBGUQG7NyPDkrt/2fivN3ws//HzLnks=`? The two slash seem to be wrong here.

Comment: I do indeed call it with that, erickson was right, it works perfectly now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare `storedHash` to `calculatedHash`. You are comparing `storedPassword`, which still has the prefix `"pbkdf2_sha256$20000$"`.